# Error during playing with keras example pretrained_word_embeddings

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, neural-network, keras, conv-neural-network

I'am trying to modify the keras example pretrained_word_embeddings that is available [here](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/examples/pretrained_word_embeddings.py) and I faced the following issue : if I decreased `MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH` varibae for example to `95` value I would get the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Program
>   Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\common_shapes.py",
>   line 670, in _call_cpp_shape_fn_impl
>       status)   File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\contextlib.py", line 66, in **exit**
>       next(self.gen)   File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\errors_impl.py",
>   line 469, in raise_exception_on_not_ok_status
>       pywrap_tensorflow.TF_GetCode(status)) tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Negative
>   dimension size caused by subtracting 5 from 2 for 'Conv2D_2' (op:
>   'Conv2D') with input shapes: [?,2,1,128], [5,1,128,128].

I need to change it in case when I for example need to work with small messages like tweets. I use a Tensorflow backend.

Please, help me to clarify 
1) What is the problem with `MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH`?
2) What is the reason that `Conv2D_2` is in trace instead of `Conv1D` that I'am using in the model.

Answer (score 8):

Let's go through network definition and analyse the shapes of layer outputs when `MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH=95`:

```
sequence_input = Input(shape=(MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH,), dtype='int32')
embedded_sequences = embedding_layer(sequence_input)
# Output shape: (95, EMBEDDING_DIM)
x = Conv1D(128, 5, activation='relu')(embedded_sequences)
# Output shape: (91, 128) (because of valid border mode) 
x = MaxPooling1D(5)(x)
# Output shape: (18, 128)
x = Conv1D(128, 5, activation='relu')(x)
# Output shape: (14, 128)
x = MaxPooling1D(5)(x)
# Output shape: (2, 128)
x = Conv1D(128, 5, activation='relu')(x)
# Output shape: (2 - 4??, 128) - PROBLEM!!
x = MaxPooling1D(35)(x) # In the easiest way - change 35 to 2.
x = Flatten()(x)
x = Dense(128, activation='relu')(x)
preds = Dense(100, activation='softmax')(x)
```

As you may see the problem lies in the last `Conv1D` layer where there is not enough dimension to apply convolution with a `valid` border mode. There are many ways how you could solve that. The easiest one is to crop the last `Conv-MaxPool` duo and change the network definition to:

```
sequence_input = Input(shape=(MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH,), dtype='int32')
embedded_sequences = embedding_layer(sequence_input)
# Output shape: (95, EMBEDDING_DIM)
x = Conv1D(128, 5, activation='relu')(embedded_sequences)
# Output shape: (91, 128) (because of valid border mode) 
x = MaxPooling1D(5)(x)
# Output shape: (18, 128)
x = Conv1D(128, 5, activation='relu')(x)
# Output shape: (14, 128)
x = MaxPooling1D(5)(x)
# Output shape: (2, 128)
x = Flatten()(x) # Here - everything is ok.
x = Dense(128, activation='relu')(x)
preds = Dense(100, activation='softmax')(x)
```

Of course - there are more way to do this (like playing with pooling size, etc.).

The reason behind using `Conv2D` comes from the fact that in case of `TensorFlow` backend a `Conv1D` are implemented by a two dimensional convolutions with one dimension squeezed to have a size of `1`.

Comment: Thank you very match! It helps me to undestand shape flow through the model.

Comment: Is there anything else I could explain?

Comment: thanks for your attentions! Several additional questions: 1) Is it reasonable   to use dropout in such model? 2) Last MaxPooling1D layer has to cover all output shape every time? At original model last conv layer output is 35 and we setup maxpool the same 35 value, in my example if we have last conv 2 so we can put maxpool as 2. 3) Am I right if to say that increase of value 128 (kernels number) will increase accuracy

Comment: This question is really wide and it's hard to respond in one comment. Please - ask this as a new question at SO.

Comment: You are right, I've just put it out to new question at SO. Please check it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42433443/questions-about-keras-example-pretrained-word-embeddings